# Referencing complex variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

How do you make the following JS variable references:

1. When you have an array (`x[0], x[1], ...`), and you have a button like so:

   ```
   <button onclick="say(0)"></button>
   ```

   The function looks like this:

   ```
   function say(src){
     // Define the box (some random div element will do)
     var box = document.querySelector('#box');

     // This is wrong, I know... I need to refer to the variable 'response[0]' in this case...
     box.innerHTML = response[src];
   }
   ```
2. When you have the following list of variables:

   ```
   var book = "Some Book";
   var shelf = "Some Shelf"
   var bookshelf = "The cake!"
   ```

In this case, if I want to (for whatever reason) refer to the variable `bookshelf`, how do I do it by combining the variable names of the other two variables?

I mean, I can't do `var x = book + shelf;` since that will give me the `result = "Some BookSome Shelf"`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make them variables, make them properties of an object:

```
var tags = {
   book: 'Some book',
   shelf: 'Some shelf',
   bookshelf: 'The Cake!'
};

var which = 'bookshelf';
var x = tags[which];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to make them properties of an object (although they're probably already properties of the `window` object):

```
var stuff = {
    book: "Some book!",
    shelf: "Some shelf",
    bookshelf: "The cake!"
};

function say(src) {
    // Define the box (some random div element will do)
    var box = document.querySelector('#box');

    box.innerHTML = stuff[response[src]];
}
```

Comment: Technically, based on your code, isn't 'stuff' now an object? And getting "The Cake!" would require you to call stuff.bookshelf...

See, my question is this: How do I get the variable `stuff.bookshelf` by dynamically referencing the bookshelf part? I surely can't do var x = book, var y = shelf, and then call stuff.x+y... That's what I'm looking for...

Comment: @Abhishek: You use the bracket syntax. Everything is an object in JavaScript. So `stuff[x + y]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't seem to be understanding the train of thought here... I'm now stuck with an error that says 'bookshelf is not defined'... :( Hmmm...

Comment: @Abhishek: What exactly did you try? Can you show a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please?